# Stack Overflow profile not accessible after associating Google accounts

Tags: support, stack-overflow, openid, authentication

I am currently facing a severe problem.

For years I had a Google account (not GMail!) which was/is registered to my e-mail address at a third-party provider. In order to use the Android market, I was forced to associate my Google account with a GMail address.

I can now use either my old e-mail address from the third-party provider or the new one from GMail to log into Google websites.

My Stack Overflow account was associated with the third-party e-mail address I used to use for login at Google. When I perform the login at Google now, it automatically switches to my new GMail address. The effect of this is that I can't access my own Stack Overflow account any more.

Do you have any suggestions about how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Email team@stackoverflow.com from the address that your account is registered with and they should be able to help your fix it. (I'd suggest you send them the new OpenID identifier to associate with your account too except I don't know how to get that from the Google login.)

Answer (score 2):

If you e-mail the StackOverflow team they can help merge your two accounts, but you can regain access to the original account simply by visiting [openid.stackexchange.com](http://openid.stackexchange.com), and then creating a new Stack Exchange account with the same third-party e-mail address that you used to use.  This should enable you to now access the old account again, using your new Stack Exchange login.